# Taking action in javascript object on duplicate key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

i have a very messy js object that i'm trying to clean up.
Do i need to create a new object in which i'll add a new element on each duplicate key occurrence ?

Basically, i'm trying to turn :

```
[ { device: 4323, action: 'CASH IN' },
  { device: 4325, action: 'ALTER DB' },
  { device: 4323, action: 'Order Pizza' } ]
```

into :

```
[ { device: 4323, action: 'CASH IN, Order Pizza' },
  { device: 4325, action: 'ALTER DB' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array.reduce:

```js
var items = [ { device: 4323, action: 'CASH IN' },
  { device: 4325, action: 'ALTER DB' },
  { device: 4323, action: 'Order Pizza' } ];
  
var res = items.reduce((m, o) => {
  var found = m.find(e => e.device === o.device);
  found ? found.action += `, ${o.action}` : m.push(o);
  return m;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var arr = [ { device: 4323, action: 'CASH IN' },
  { device: 4325, action: 'ALTER DB' },
  { device: 4323, action: 'Order Pizza' } ];
  
  var map = {}; // map stores key as device and value as index of array
  var counter = 1; // counter to manage index
  var result = []; // the result array
  arr.forEach(function(item){ // iterating over array
    if(map[item.device]) { // check for existence of device in map
      // if exists only update its action in array
      result[map[item.device] - 1].action =  result[map[item.device] - 1].action + ", " + item.action; 
    } else { // if does not exist, set device in map and push object in result array
      map[item.device] = counter++;
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  console.log(result);
```